# Is it possible to turn off iCloud Photo Library on one device only?

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, macos, photos, photos.app

I would like to know if its possible to turn off iCloud Photo Library on one of my devices. The device in question is a MacBook Air which I use while at the office during the day. I would like to keep photos on for my iPhone, iMac, and MacBook Pro. Anyone know if this is possible on a device level?

I might add the reason that I would like to know if this is possible. I’m noticing the photo processes are using high CPU as well as kernel_task. I’m attempting to minimize CPU.

[image: Activity Monitor]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your MacBook Air, open **** → **System Preferences** → **iCloud** and *uncheck* **Photos**.

[image: iCloud Preferences]

This will prevent iCloud Photos from syncing to and from the device on which you did this.

On iOS, this is done by going into **Settings** → **Photos** and *disabling* **iCloud Photo Library**.

Comment: Yes, I use iCloud photo library. If I turn of this feature from my MacBook Air, I will have disabled iCloud photo library on an account level and on all of my devices, hence compromising my iCloud library. Right?

Comment: No, it will *not* disable it at the account level, only on the computer that you disable syncing from. Disabling at the account level is done by going into **Manage…** → **Photo Library** → **Disable and Delete**.